# "to eat a Hero" (Seinfeld)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Another odd line from the famous TV show. What does it mean, *to eat a Hero*? ([the full script](http://www.siyumhaseinfeld.com/eps/scripts/S515-ThePie.html))

> ELAINE: (piffling) I once broke up with someone for not offering me pie.
>
> JERRY: You did?
>
> ELAINE: He could be **eating a Hero**, he wouldn't offer me anything. It's a sickness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Hero" is a NY city area regionalism for [**submarine sandwich**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_sandwich) aka the **sub, hoagie, grinder,** or **spuckie**.

I suspect, but cannot prove, that it actually comes from the Greek "gyro", which when pronounced as in Greek, has an aspirated "g" and comes out sounding an awful lot like "hyero".  A gyro is a long cylindrical sandwich (though, unlike a hero, it is constructed by rolling, not by stuffing a cylindrical length of bread), and large numbers of Greek immigrants to the US started working in (and taking over) Italian sub shops, so it seems likely enough, but the wikipedia article claims the timing doesn't work out.

Comment: I suppose you never know, but I have to say I think it's bogglingly unlikely that the kind of people who invent informal names for sandwiches would borrow from ancient Greek. But I do seem to recall from my holidays in Greece that *gyros* were some kind of "finger food" - maybe like little doner kebabs, I don't recall exactly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not the ancient Greek, the perfectly modern Greek that the Greek workers in the Italian sub shops shout at each other. (I do not know why there are so many Greeks owning Italian sub shops, but here abouts it is a thing.)  Do you not have [gyros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyro_(food)) where you are?

Comment: We don't actually have any Greek eateries round my way (not that I eat out much these days anyway). There's an excellent place down the road that does ***kebabs***, but they're pretty substantial. Their "standard" kebab has a whole chicken breast, plus shedloads of salad packed into a pitta bread. The "large" has two breasts, and the "kingsize" has *three* fat chicken breasts. From what I remember of the "gyros" I was offered in Greece, they were pretty "snacky" little bites to nibble on, often given free with your beer, like *tapas* in Spain.

Comment: The word, as applied to sandwiches, is spelled sometimes *gyro* and sometimes *hero*. Here is an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gyro+sandwich%2Chero+sandwich%2Csubmarine+sandwich%2C+hoagie%2C+poor+boy+sandwich&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgyro%20sandwich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chero%20sandwich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubmarine%20sandwich%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Choagie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoor%20boy%20sandwich%3B%2Cc0), FWIW.

Comment: Gyros around here (northeastern US) are served in round pita bread, which is then rolled up, into a shaped resembling a cone more than a cylinder. Possibly etymology http://www.bonappetit.com/test-kitchen/ingredients/article/the-origin-of-hoagies-grinders-subs-heroes-and-spuckies

Comment: `Barry Popik, ... OED contributor and general food word expert, traces the word back to a 1937 Lexicon of Trade Jargon published by the WPA, which describes “hero” as “armored car guards jargon” for a big sandwich.`

Comment: @TimRomano Okay, but were they _Greek_ armored car guards?  According to McGoldrick et al citing Moskos (1989), the "great wave" of Greek immigration to major cities of the US east coast, especially NYC, was 1890-1917, and being about a half a million people, mostly men from rural areas, and unskilled.  Anybody know if Greek men were particularly represented in the armored car guard profession?

Comment: @Codeswitcher: gyro->hero is not implausible. But Merriam Webster Dictionary dates the first attested use of gyro (sandwich) to 1971. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gyro

Comment: @TimRomano Oooh, nice find!

Comment: @TimRomano However, wikipedia tells us "_gyros_ is derived from the Turkish _doner kebab_, which was invented in Bursa in the 19th century" and it cites Kenneth F. Kiple, Kriemhild Coneè Ornelas, eds., Cambridge World History of Food, Cambridge, 2000. ISBN 0-521-40216-6. Vol. 2, p. 1147.  Presumably that 1971 first-use date is the date of earliest written attestation of "gyros" in _English_.